# Xubuntu vs XFCE in Ubuntu issue

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

After installing Xubuntu from its own iso, the desktop is slow to load up after putting in name and password. After installing Ubuntu, and then install XFCE through terminal, and deleting Unity, there is no slowdown. Please note, the slowdown only starts after the recommended updates are applied, not the required ones.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. What do you mean by Xubuntu vs Xubuntu?

Comment: @penreturn Maybe he means XFCE desktop environment in Ubuntu (remove Unity then use XFCE on Ubuntu)

Comment: That is what I meant. Sorry if I was unclear.